# How to use pandas.cut() (or equivalent) in dask efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

## Is there an equivalent to pandas.cut() in Dask?

I try to bin and group a large dataset in Python. It is a list of measured electrons with the properties (positionX, positionY, energy, time). I need to group it along positionX, positionY and do binning in energy classes.

So far I could do it with pandas, but I would like to run it in parallel. So, I try to use dask.

The groupby method works very well, but unfortunately, I run into difficulties when trying to *bin* the data in energy.  I found a solution using pandas.cut(), but it requires to call compute() on the raw dataset (turning it essentialy into non-parallel code). Is there an equivalent to pandas.cut() in dask, or is there another (elegant) way to achieve the same functionality?

```
import dask 
# create dask dataframe from the array
dd = dask.dataframe.from_array(mainArray, chunksize=100000, columns=('posX','posY', 'time', 'energy'))

# Set the bins to bin along energy
bins = range(0, 10000, 500)

# Create the cut in energy (using non-parallel pandas code...)
energyBinner=pandas.cut(dd['energy'],bins)

# Group the data according to posX, posY and energy
grouped = dd.compute().groupby([energyBinner, 'posX', 'posY'])

# Apply the count() method to the data:
numberOfEvents = grouped['time'].count()
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do `dd['energy'].map_partitions(pd.cut, bins)`.